# Insertion of dynamic values to specific colums using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a new row into a table, but one column's value insertion is dependent on a specific rule.
So far I get an error because SQL doesn't support my way and I have no idea what to do:

```
INSERT INTO RNFIL170
VALUES ('somthing1',0, 0, null,null,0, select max(RNFIL170.SEDER_HATZAGA)+1 from RNFIL170 , 0 , 0,1, 'somthing2');
```

How can I insert the max(RNFIL170.SEDER_HATZAGA)+1 into RNFIL170 ?

Comment: Looks what you actually need is an `IDENTITY` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT..` synxtax

Always specify the column list in the destination table

```
INSERT INTO RNFIL170 ( {column name list} )
SELECT 'somthing1',0, 0, null,null,0, max(RNFIL170.SEDER_HATZAGA)+1, 0 , 0,1, 'somthing2'
FROM   RNFIL170 ;
```

Comment: I would recommend using an `ISNULL(max(RNFIL170.SEDER_HATZAGA),0)+1` to avoid any issue if the table is empty